# How to make AJAX read back response without page's source and without JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, forms

I use the following code to submit a form:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#myForm').attr('action'),
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    /*dataType: 'html json', *///tell the server that you expect json 
    data: {
        "num"     : $('#myNum').val(), 
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        if ( check_validate() == 1) {
            alert(response);
        }
        else {}
    }
});
```

Then in the PHP `index.php` I have:

```
if (isset($_POST["num"])) {
    $num = $_POST["num"];
    if($num == 1) 
        echo "sure!"; 
}
```

The JS popups with the `sure!` and the whole `index.php` page source code. Is there a way to remove the source code and just have the response show without setting the `dataType` to `JSON`?

Comment: die(), exit ... is your friend!

Comment: so presumably you've got more code/html after your little `if()` block? Just `exit()` once you've output "sure!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply stop script execution after output:

```
//must be before any other output, eg at top of file
if (isset($_POST["num"])) {
    $num = $_POST["num"];
    if($num == 1) 
        echo "sure!";
        die(); 
}
```

Comment: The `return;` was throwing me an error. The `die();` worked just like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_POST["num"])) {
    $num = $_POST["num"];
    if($num == 1) 
        echo "sure!";
    return; 
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I didn't have reputation enough to post comments, now I do :)